# Calculating a median reimbursement of a policy under a policy limit.

Tags: exponential-distribution

An insurance policy reimburses losses incurred by a policyholder subject to a limit of 1000. Losses follow an exponential distribution with mean 500.

Calculate the median reimbursement for this policy.

a.) 26
b.) 347
c.) 490
d.) 504
e.) 750

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $X$ be the loss incurred such that $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(1/500)$.

Let $Y$ be the payout.

What can you say about the distribution of $Y$ for $x<1000$? What can you say about the distribution of $Y$ for $x\ge1000$?

At which range does $F_Y(y)=0.5$?